# How to investigate "Unable to create object the system cannot find the file specified" error on deployment machine

Tags: c++, dll, com, acrobat-sdk

I have a c++ project (acrobat pdf plugin) that uses a com visable c# dll. On my pc everything is working perfectly but on my deployment server I get the error "Unable to create object". I have registered the dll on the deployment machine using regasm and created the .tlb file on the same location of the dll. I used comxplorer and I compared the clsid of the components between my machine and the deployment machine, and they match.

this com dll does use other dlls (it's a pretty big project)

Can late binding or something like that help me? How can I begin to investigating this issue?

Please advise

Comment: `procmon` filtered on CreateFile failures is one way, albeit somewhat manual.

Comment: @WhozCraig what do you mean?

Comment: I mean use sys internals [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to capture events related to failed CreateFile calls for your process. The missing mystery DLL(s) will be in the list. there are other ways, but that is pretty straight up (and its a helluva tool, btw).

Comment: You are right this is great. It shows that I have no idea how com works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I register the com dll I need to add /codebase e.g.

```
...\regasm.exe "c:\foo.dll" /codebase
```